# developing an app which capture video and marks time range on cross platform

Tags: c#, php, windows, ipad, php-gtk

i would like to develop an app. So when i finish to develop that, i would like to it works on cross platform (etc. Windows, IOS - iPad - )

This app must capture video from webcam or other video source and when it is capturing video i would like to mark video's current timestamp to db or any file (etc. xml). Also that can be desktop or web app.

I can use PHP, C# and clint side web tecnologies (etc. jQuery, CSS, HTML ...)

Can you suggest, how can i do that with my programming experiences. Or which programming tecnologies must i learn?

I heard PHP-GTK. Is it ideal for me?

Thank you already now.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), which is a layer between the different mobile OS'es and your application.

This way you don't have to port your application to all platforms, but simply code it against their API and it'll access the camera for you.

Comment: I don't want to develop my app just for mobile platform. When i will develop that, it able to work with any other external video source not just phone cams and able to work on desktop platform. Also thank you for your interest.

Comment: I cannot think of any framework that lets you create one app for both mobile and desktop use.